# Сравнение 2-х текстовых файлов

Tags: c#, .net

Сравниваю 1 и 2 текстовый файл, если в 1 нету тех строк, которые во 2 текстовом файле, то он создает третий текстовый файл и записывает в него. Как ускорить весь процесс, так как это очень долго, занимает очень много оперативной памяти при работе, объем текстовых файлов размером более 1 гб, сейчас работает такой код:

```
var file1 = File.ReadLines("file1.txt");
var file2 = File.ReadLines("file2.txt");
File.WriteAllLines("Result.txt", file2.Except(file1));
```

Аналоги которую сортируют ПО так же, занимают при сравнении на много меньше ресурсов и работают шустрее.

Comment: Попробуйте читать по строкам.

Comment: попробовать работать в нескольких потоках

Answer (score 1):

1. Ошибка номер раз - вы читаете весь файл2 в память
2. Ошибка номер два - вы фильтруете по всей последовательности file2.Except(file1), что неэффективно на больших коллекциях
3. Ошибка номер три - вы читаете файл1 по строкам, хотя вам он нужен в памяти целиком. Это имееет смысл только если у вас в файле1 очень много повторяющихся строк, в противном случае вы просто жертвуете производительностью на пустом месте (читать файл по строке гораздо медленней, чем читать файл целиком)
4. Четыре, если вы хотите ускроить работу с файлами, то читайте с буфером и пишите с буфером.

Вот как ваш код может примерно выглядеть:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt")) set.Add(line);

// размеры буфера установите сами как вам надо, я для пример указал 10 мб
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite("Result.txt"), 10*1024*1024 ))) 
{
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead("file2.txt"), 10*1024*1024)))
    {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (!set.Contains(line)) sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Если предположить, что изначальные файлы сортированы и не содержат дублткатов, то задача становится абсолютно другой и не требует большого потребления памяти - достаточно считывать файлы по строке. Я только добавил буферы на чтение и запись, то есть в итоге програма должна отъедать немного памяти.

Корректность проверяйте сами.

```
var f1 = @"D:\temp\1071344\file1.txt";
var f2 = @"D:\temp\1071344\file2.txt";
var ret = @"D:\temp\1071344\Result.txt";

using (var sr1 = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(f1), 10 * 1024 * 1024)))
{
    using (var sr2 = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(f2), 10 * 1024 * 1024)))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.Open(ret, FileMode.Create), 10 * 1024 * 1024)))
        {
            if (sr2.EndOfStream) return;

            if (sr1.EndOfStream)
            {
                while (!sr2.EndOfStream) sw.WriteLine(sr2.ReadLine());
                return;
            }

            var l1 = sr1.ReadLine();
            var l2 = sr2.ReadLine();

            while (!sr1.EndOfStream || !sr2.EndOfStream)
            {
                if (sr1.EndOfStream)
                {
                    while (!sr2.EndOfStream) sw.WriteLine(sr2.ReadLine());
                    return;
                }

                if (sr2.EndOfStream) return;

                var comp = string.Compare(l1, l2);
                if (comp < 0) l1 = sr1.ReadLine();
                if (comp == 0)
                {
                    l1 = sr1.ReadLine();
                    l2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                }
                if (comp > 0)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(l2);
                    l2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При старте работы, через некоторое время получаю ошибку System.OutOfMemoryException: "Выдано исключение типа "System.OutOfMemoryException"."

Comment: Если первый файл не влезает в память, замените `File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt")` на `File.ReadLines("file1.txt")`

Comment: Данный способ не подходит, забирает слишком много RAM до 3 гб

Comment: Есть возможность выложить пример ваших файлов?

Comment: Там просто список электронных адресов клиентов через строку и так с размером текстового файла гигабайт.

Comment: Этот список электронных адресов сортированный в обоих файлах? Или они идут в любом порядке? Вам на выхоже порядок надо сохранить или результаты могут в любом порядке идти?

Comment: Результаты в любом порядке. К примеру вот сравниваю 2 текстовых файла, если в 1 текстовом файле нету тех адресов, которые во 2, то он записывает в 3 текстовый файл. Просто нужно чтобы оперативку не забирала под 3-4 гб и работали быстрее.

Comment: Результаты в любом порядке, а исходные файлы? Вы же понимаете, что это важный вопрос? Если исходные файлы сортированы, то это в корне меняет дело.

Comment: файлы отсортированы

Comment: @reb00t обновил ответ, проверяйте только не правильность результаты сами.

Comment: После вашего кода, не выполняется остальной код. Хочу после завершения сортировки, появился MessageBox, но он не появляется.

Comment: Я не знаю ничего по ваши MessageBox'ы. У вас ошибка какая-то возникает? Выходной файл создался? Он корректный? Это можете только вы проверить, так как исходные файлы только у вас есть.

Comment: Все работает и выходной файл создался, но после я хочу вывести в консоль о том что процесс сортировки завершен, но после Вашего кода, никакой остальной не работает после. Получается после нажатия кнопки создается выходной файл, но в консоль не выводит сообщение, о что процесс завершен.

Comment: Оберните мой код в try-catch, добавьте логгирование, запустите все под отладчиком, смотрите что происходит и где код застревает

Comment: проблему нашел, цикл продолжает работу и не выполняется мой отрывок кода после Вашего. Попытался остановить цикл сортировки с помощью break, но цикл останавливается полностью. Как возможно закончить цикл и продолжить работать дальше?

Comment: Какой конкретно цикл? Вы о каком коде сейчас говорите? О моем коде из моего ответа? О вашем коде из вашего вопроса? Или о коде, который вообще к вопросу не относится?

Comment: О вашем коде, он не прекращает цикл и тот код, который должен выполняться после вашего кода (цикла), не выполняется

Comment: В моем коде 3 цикла, вы про какой говорите? Вы код мой точно скопировали? Нигде не опечатались? Код где то застревает или просто цикл крутится бесконечно? Считывание из файлов происходит когда цикл замыкается? По идее, все циклы должны закончиться, когда оба файла (или хотя бы второй) считаны до конца